# Programmatically inspect .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis

I am looking for a way to programmatically inspect a .NET (C#, VB.NET,..) source code to perform static code analysis.

I'd like to perform queries on the code such as:
- list classes whose name begin by x
- list all the subclasses of x
- list methods which instanciate an object of class x
- determine if method x contains a variable named y
- list methods calling the method y
- ...

What I am looking for is an API or something else allowing me to write programs able to examine a source code.

Answer (score 9):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) gives a SQL-like query language for querying .NET code structure.

Comment: Brilliant tool. +1 for NDepend recommendation.

Comment: Where's the programmatic interface in NDepend?  In other words how can it be used from my own C# code?

Comment: I believe NDepend has some sort of programming/query language... however that's the limit of my knowledge. I guess you'd have to contact the NDepend people directly.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer, I describe more details concerning the NDepend programming/query language.

Answer (score 5):

You can use System.Reflection, that should do the trick nicely for some of the things you want. As far as getting into the IL itself, check out Mono's [Cecil](http://mono-project.com/Cecil).

Comment: Unless, @monkeyget is looking at the source code. Then they'll probably want a parser.

Comment: Or a compiler :). Yea I uh missed that he said "source code". I guess NDepend and some of the IDE plugins might be of assistance then. Sorry!

Comment: System.Reflection is indeed an option which i'll look into but it seems limited and i'm sure there must exist more powerful and simple tools for what I want to do.
I mentioned source code in the question but a tool working on IL would be ok too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) for static code analysis?

Comment: Because he wants to WRITE software that will allow him to do what FxCop does.

Answer (score 1):

See the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).

DMS provides parsers that automatically build ASTs for many languages (C, C++, Java, C# [1.2, 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0], COBOL, ECMAScript, PHP, Verilog, ..) as well as symbol tables and control and data flow analysis for several of these.

DMS's pattern language can be used to match surface-syntax patterns, and combined with procedural analysis to ties code elements together with symbol table entries and various data flow relations.  It has been used to implement a wide variety of program analysis tools, and is designed to be a foundation for you to build you own tool, without wasting a vast amount of time building basic program analysis infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the code model in Reflector? With the code model view add-in you should be able to get the idea of how to interrogate the structure of the code.

Answer (score 0):

What about StyleCop? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis. But it doesn't support APIs.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the stusmith's answer, NDepend seems to be what you are looking for. NDepend lets write **Code Queries and Rules over LINQ Queries**, (what we call [CQLinq](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL)). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

For example here are some CQLinq queries:

-> list classes whose name begin by x

```
from t in Application.Types.WithNameLike("^x")
where t.IsClass select t
```

-> list all the subclasses of x

```
from t in Application.Types
where t.DeriveFrom("MyNamespace.MyTypeX")
select t
```

-> list methods which instanciate an object of class x

```
from m in Application.Methods
where m.CreateA("MyNamespace.MyTypeX")
select m
```

-> list methods calling the method y - ...

```
from m in Application.Methods
where m.IsUsing("MyNamespace.MyType.MyMethodY()")
select m
```

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default. Customizing existing rules or creating your own rules is straightforward thanks to the *well-known* C# LINQ syntax.

CQLinq queries can be edited live in VisualStudio, and offer instant result, with browsing facilities:

[image]

Actually, CQLinq is based on [NDepend.API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html), and more specifically on types in the namespace [NDepend.CodeModel](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel_namespace.html). With NDepend.API you can write programs to do things more tricky tghan just CQLinq queries, for example we wrote a [Code Duplicate Finder tool](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2012/06/12/an-original-algorithm-to-find-net-code-duplicate/) with NDepend.API.

Rules can be verified [live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) and at Build Process time, in a [generated HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn) for this.

Comment: Because the OP said 'programmatically inspect .. source code' and that is what Roslyn is all about. The idea of using the framework as C# itself will use is very appealing.